# OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE in STIM

Tags: stim

I was going through the example_honeycomb_circuit.stim code available on page 17 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.10457.pdf. I am curious about the rationale behind selecting the choice of rec[-k] for OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE. Is it determined based on one's understanding of the logical Z observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(1) rec[-3]` means "add the third most recent measurement to the growing pile of measurements used to define the ultimate logical measurement of observable 1". You have to look at the previous bits of the circuit to see which measurement that corresponds to.

The reason the syntax is done in a way where you refer backwards relative to the present is to make it work inside loops, or after loops without having to explicitly depend on all the loops' repetition counts.

Comment: Thank you so much!